# FFMPEG hls_time & hls_init_time together not working

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I am using ffmpeg v4.4, trying to split HLS segments(.ts) by initial segment with 4sec and rest with 10sec using this command, but segments are generating only with hls_init_time, hls_time is not applying:

`ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -profile:v main -level 3.0 -preset veryslow -force_key_frames expr:gte\(t,n_forced*1\) -g 30 -keyint_min 30 -f hls -hls_segment_type mpegts -hls_flags single_file -hls_init_time 4 -hls_time 8 -hls_list_size 20 output.m3u8`

I need to Generate single .ts file with byte ranges, first chunk byte range is 6 sec duration and rest all chunks with 12 sec byte ranges

I tried to keep key_frame different lengths of 1sec, 3sec, 6sec, and hls_list_size=0 also, but nothing working, What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a bug. For now, use `-force_key_frames expr:if(eq(t,4),1,not(mod(t-4,8)))`

Comment: Thanks @Gyan for the response, tried with the above but not working no change in the Playlist file.